# Filter data with custom method in ruby model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one method `translate`  in my model class (i. e 
HolaMilindPatel ) which I call from controller after data is retrieved from database.  Please refer below code Example:

```
def show
    @center = Center.find(params[:id])
    render json: {status: 'success', data: 
    HolaMilindPatel.translate(@center)}, status: :ok
end
```

Now what I want Is, I want this method to be called after `center. find(params[i])` instead of explicitly called in controller as shown in above code snippet. Is there any way I can call `translate` method implicitly after `find`

Comment: I could not understand what you're saying. Especially the first line.

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry it was confusing earlier.  Should be less confusing now :) @Ratata

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to translate after `find` automatically?

If so, you can do with the code below.

```
class Center < ApplicationRecord
  after_find do |center|
    HolaMilindPatel.translate(center)
  end
end
```

Comment: If i use `Center.all` then it works ? if not then suggest for `Center.all` and `Center.where()`

Comment: @ArunVaishnav Will not you try it? Let's read guides. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#running-callbacks